# CS Cart API Max requests

Tags: php, cs-cart

I have a csv with 30k records, with product ids and their new prices. I want to make a PHP script that will open the csv, loop through it and use CSCart API to update prices of the products. The requests are done using cURL and my question is can the server afford 30k api requests in 1 go?

Comment: Post the code where you got stuck.

Comment: well, I haven't code it because I don't know if I can do so many cURL requests in one go, if its possible then I will code it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually the answer depends on the server configuration (memory and time limit). In official API documentation there are no any limits regarding the amount of items which can be received in one go:

http://docs.cs-cart.com/4.3.x/api/index.html